# bash nested loop running through outer loop before running through inner loop

Tags: json, bash, loops, for-loop

When execute the following portion of the bash script it is looping through the outter array before it loops through inner array or at least that's what it appears to be doing.

```
    for i in "${linkedTickets[@]}"
    do
        array=($( cat ${WORKDIR}/${i}_curl.log |
                egrep 'Depend' |
                sed 's/depends on//g; s/[][\"[:space:]]//g; s/fields,//g; s/issuelinks,//g; s/,type//g; s/,outward//g; s/outwarddependson//g; s/,name//g; s/Depend//g;' | tr -d '\040\011\015' | tr '\n' ' '))
        var=$i
        if [ ${#array[@]} -ne 0 ]; then
                echo ""
                echo "${!array[@]} --  ${array[@]}"
                echo "$var"
                for j in "${array[@]}"
                do
                        cat "$WORKDIR/${var}_curl.log" |
                                grep -R "\[\"fields\",\"issuelinks\",${j},\"outwardIssue\",\"fields\",\"status\",\"name\"\]" |
                                sort -u
                done
        fi
done
```

The output looks like this:

```
0 --  0
PROJ-198
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-1233_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",0,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]  "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-188_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",0,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-198_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",0,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-204_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",0,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-209_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",0,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-1371_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",0,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]  "On Hold"

0 1 2 3 4 5 --  0 1 2 3 4 5
PROJ-186
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-16114_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",0,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"] "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-1142_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",0,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]  "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-172_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",0,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-180_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",0,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-182_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",0,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-185_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",0,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-186_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",0,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-187_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",0,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-188_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",0,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-198_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",0,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-204_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",0,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-209_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",0,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-1371_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",0,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]  "On Hold"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-16114_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",1,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"] "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-172_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",1,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-180_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",1,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-182_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",1,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-185_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",1,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-186_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",1,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-187_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",1,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-188_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",1,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-200_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",1,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Deployed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-201_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",1,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Deployed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-16114_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",2,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"] "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-180_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",2,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-182_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",2,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-185_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",2,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-186_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",2,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-198_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",2,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Deployed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-199_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",2,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Deployed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-209_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",2,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-16114_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",3,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"] "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-182_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",3,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-186_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",3,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-209_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",3,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Deployed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-16114_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",4,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"] "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-186_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",4,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-16114_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",5,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"] "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-186_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",5,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Deployed"

0 --  0
PROJ-209
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-16114_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",0,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"] "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-1142_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",0,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]  "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-172_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",0,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-180_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",0,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-1371_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",0,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]  "On Hold"
```

Probably just making some silly mistakes.  But some background to what I'm doing here, I'm passing a Jira ticket to this bash script and it's curling the ticket via the version 2 api from Atlassian and parsing out the JSON like above, then I'm grabbing the linked tickets throwing them in linkedTickets[@] and looping through that a few times in the script to then curl those tickets to generate my curl logs, and once complete I'm searching for dependencies, the two loops above that I'm having trouble with are just searching through the issuelink #'s to find depedency for that one ticket #, however it's looping through $i inside the loop for $j to completion instead of once through $i and all the way through $j before going back to $i.  Is this a case of using a for loop when I should be using a while loop on the inside?

```
0 --  0
PROJ-189
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-189_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",0,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
0 --  0
PROJ-195
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-195_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",0,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
0 --  0
PROJ-200
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-200_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",0,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"]   "Closed"
0 --  0
PROJ-209
PN/PROJ-16114/PROJ-16114_curl.log:["fields","issuelinks",0,"outwardIssue","fields","status","name"] "Closed"
```

I look forward to any feedback, hopefully I won't get hammered to hard for my syntax as I'm sure it's rough at best very probably incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the quotes off your loop inputs.

```
for i in "${a[*]}"; do echo $i; done
1 2 3

for i in ${a[*]}; do echo $i; done
1
2
3
```